# How to supress layout analysis for PDFMiner in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pdfminer

The PDFMiner.six gets stuck on certain files with  resolution images and text present, so i figured if i could suppress the layout analysis, it might skip these pages and move on.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

abspath_pdf = r'C:\\Users\\shricharan.arumugam\\Desktop\\Baraka East_1 Ichron REPORT Final.pdf'



def convert_pdf_to_txt2(path):   
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8' 
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    i=1
    #test_pages=PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):

        interpreter.process_page(page)
        print(i)
        i=i+1

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text

convert_pdf_to_txt2(abspath_pdf)
```

The documentation says to use -n , to suppress layout analysis, but can someone show me how to use that?

Answer (score 0):

H Shricharan - try setting laparams = None immediately after the call laparams = LAParams().  (I left the call to LAParams() in there just in case it calls some initialization code I need, but then overwrote laparams with None in the next line).  That's what the code in pdf2txt.py seems to do.  I was having the same problem as you, and so far (fingers crossed) that seems to have fixed it.  (ie - it seems to be immensely faster and is not getting stuck on certain files, but the downside is that it now seems to just return the converted text as one long string, no paragraphs, line breaks, etc.. so not sure if that will work for you or not)  -Mark

Comment: Thank you for the response. i'll test it and get back to you.